# Rotate Meshviewer in multiple axis

Tags: javafx

I tried to perform a rotate on a meshviewer with multiple axis

```
Meshviewer.setRotateAxis (Rotate.X_Axis);
Meshviewer.setRotate(100);
Meshviewer.setRotateAxis(Rotate.Y_Axis);
Meshviewer.setRotate (100);
```

It should be rotated in x and y direction but it only rotated in y direction.
What's wrong?

[Written on smartphone]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rotateAxis` is a property like any other. If you did

```
someObject.setValue(5);
someObject.setValue(3);
```

you would (I assume) expect

```
someObject.getValue();
```

to evaluate to `3`, not some combination of `3` and `5`. So after the code you posted, the rotation axis of `MeshViewer` is the y axis, and so it is rotated around that axis.

If you want to perform a combination of rotations about multiple axes, you can add transformations to the transforms list:

```
Rotate rotateAboutX = new Rotate(100, Rotate.X_AXIS);
Rotate rotateAboutY = new Rotate(100, Rotate.Y_AXIS);
MeshViewer.getTransforms().addAll(rotateAboutX, rotateAboutY);
```

Comment: Still trying to get all of Java FX :D Thanks, I'll try it :)

Comment: Works fine, thanks. For other people who read this. If you want to have the current rotation angle you can get them through the transformation properties...